# When is $\frac {t^a - 1} {t^b -1} $ an integer?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, fractions, integers

Given three positive integers $t$, $a$ and $b$, I'm interested to know when the fraction $$\frac {t^a - 1} {t^b -1} $$ is an integer itself. Excluding any trivial cases, by trying out different values I've come to the following conjecture:
$$\frac {t^a - 1} {t^b -1} \in \mathbb{Z} \iff a\equiv 0\pmod b $$
However I haven't had any luck proving this or finding any counter-examples.
Any hint is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Set $a=bk$ and do factorization.

Comment: Well, we do know $(t^b -1)(t^{bn}+ t^{(n-1)b} + ..... + 1) = t^{(n+1)b} -1$ ....

Comment: @JonathanRichardLombardy That only proves one direction.

Comment: to prove the other direction see that every root of denominator is a root of numerator.

Comment: Note for $b < a$, and $a = kb + d;d<b$, $\frac {t^a - 1}{t^b - 1} = t^{a-b} + t^{a-2b} +..... + t^{a-kb=d} +R$ .  This is integer iff $d=0$ ( that is if t is integer of course).

Answer (score 1):

Fix $b$ and $t$ and consider the question of which $a$ are such that $\frac{t^a - 1}{t^b - 1}$ is an integer; i.e., such that $t^a \equiv 1 \pmod{t^b - 1}$. Clearly, the order of $t$ within the multiplicative group of (invertible) integers modulo $t^b - 1$ is $b$ (as every smaller positive power of $t$ is strictly between $1$ and $(t^b - 1) + 1$). Thus, the answer to our question is those $a$ which are multiples of $b$, just as you conjectured.

Comment: Nice and elegant proof. Thank you.